# how to get the content of selected item in combo box?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

i am trying to get the value of combo box selected item, but instead it returns this "BakeShop.Category".

```
namespace BakeShop
{

class Oclist
{

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Oclist()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>
        {
            new Category() { Name = "Dry Ingridients", Series = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            { "Flour", "Cake Flour", "Baking Soda" } },

            new Category() { Name = "Wet Ingridients", Series = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            { "Egg", "Coffee liqueur", "Vodka" } },

            new Category() { Name = "Chocolate", Series = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            { "Dark", "Light", "Crushed", "Chips"} }
        };
    }
}
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Series { get; set; }
```

xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CategoryCBox"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      MaxDropDownHeight="100"
                      Height="20" SelectedIndex="0"
                      FontSize="11"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="TypeCBox"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Series, ElementName=CategoryCBox}"
                      SelectionChanged="TypeCBox_SelectionChanged"
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                      Height="20"
                      FontSize="11"/>
```

and when i do this

```
string Selected = CategoryCBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString()
MessageBox.Show(Selected);
```

it shows "BakeShop.Category"

thanks guys! :)

Comment: Items in `CategoryCBox` are of type `BakeShope.Category`, so when you try to access `CategoryCBox.SelectedItem` it will be that object and doing `.ToString()` will give you the type name. What you want to do is cast the `SelectedItem` to `Category` and access required properties on that. Also, are you trying to get value from `CategoryCBox` or `TypeCBox`?

Comment: Have you tried SelectedValue ?

Comment: @OddmarDam yes. it has the same result. showing "Bakery.Category

Comment: @sthotakura i'm trying to get the value of Name from CategoryCbox(Wet Ingredients, dry Ingredients, Chocolate) and the series From TypeCBox(Flour, Cake flour, Baking Soda) sorry im a newbie i am not really familiar with the terminologies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using DataBinding to set `ItemsSource` on both `ComboBox`es, but then using `SelectionChanged` event to get data from those out. I think, the right way would be to 
use DataBinding to get selected values as well.

Your XAML would look like something below:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CategoryCBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          MaxDropDownHeight="100"
          Height="20" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
          FontSize="11"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="TypeCBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Series, ElementName=CategoryCBox}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSeries}"
          Height="20"
          FontSize="11"/>
```

You need to also add these two properties: `SelectedCategory` and `SelectedSeries` to the `Oclist` class.

```
public Category SelectedCategory { get; set; }

public string SelectedSeries { get; set; }
```

Read more about DataBinding on docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Also, here is an excellent [blogpost](https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/) on WPF ComboBox.

### **EDIT**

If you just want to get your code working, then change this to the following;

```
string Selected = ((Category)CategoryCBox.SelectedItem).Name;
MessageBox.Show(Selected);
```

But the right way would be to go with proper `DataBinding` approach.

Comment: Still i get "BakeShop.Category" in my message box :(

Comment: my message box should say ("Dry Ingredients") if i select Dry Ingredients in CategoryCbox

Answer (score 1):

You can get `Category` from `SelectedItem` property of `ComboBox`.

`SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` is an object thus you need to parse it into `Category`.

Example:

1. `Category category = yourComboBox.SelectedItem as Category`
   or
2. `Category category = (Category)yourComboBox.SelectedItem`

Answer (score 0):

In the ComboBox, create a binding to the selected item

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CategoryCBox"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      MaxDropDownHeight="100"
                      SelectedItem ="{Binding CategoryCBoxItem}"
                      Height="20" SelectedIndex="0"
                      FontSize="11"/>
```

Then in your View Model, Create a binding property

```
private string categoryCBoxItem;
public string CategoryCBoxItem
{
    get { return categoryCBoxItem; }
    set { SetProperty(ref categoryCBoxItem, value); }
}
```